# How to set up Chrome and Chromedriver to host it online

Tags: flask, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, render.com

I have a `flask` app that triggers a `selenium` script on `/scrape` route, I have deployed the app on [render.com](https://render.com) the app is working perfectly to test it I have defined a `custom_hello()` on `/` route and by that I can confirm that flask is working perfectly.
When I try to redirect `/scrape` which triggers the script, it fails because of multiple reasons -

- It cannot get `Chromedriver` path and `google-chrome binary` path
- `FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'google-chrome'`
- `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`

#### What I have tried

I looked online to solve the chromedriver issue in the python script itself and found a couple of python libraries -

- `chrome-driver-binary`
- `get-chrome-driver`
- `chromedriver`

I read the instruction on `pypy` and tried with these as well but the issue was same.

I tried downloading chrome browser itself into the server, so used `wget` in the build setting so that it would install the chrome-browser, but it does not allow me to use `sudo` command to build the installed browser(if you know what I mean)

And for anyone to see the code -

##### Imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import os
```

##### code

```
    # Set up ChromeDriver path
    chrome_driver_path = '/path/to/chromedriver'
    # Set Chrome options
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run ChromeDriver in headless mode

    # Create a new ChromeDriver instance
    service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

**for anyone suggesting about the `chrome_driver_path` yes I tried to modify it as well when I used `get-chromedriver` and `get-chrome-binary`**

The code was not always like this, every time I pushed some changes while debugging it and tried to deploy it, if you want to take a look at all the commit you can check them [here](https://github.com/priyanshu87694/selenium-scrapper-01/commits/main)

I just want help from someone who has deployed this kind of application, where you make a request and `selenium` script is triggered, I know hosting platforms do not provide support for `chrome` or `chromedriver` I am curious as how to deploy this app and make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked for me, and should work for anyone who is going through this trouble, weather you have an API or a simple selenium script that works on your local environment but not on cloud or hosting.

Please read the full answer the `docker run` command section is in the last, you need to use that command to run your script/app successfully.

#### You need to run the script in a container

You will need to add following code to `Dockerfile` and have to host it using that `Dockerfile`, trust me that is the simplest and easiest way possible, if you are thinking of trying `selenium/standalone-chrome` image then good luck you are going to configure your script a lot accordingly.
Instead just configure `Dockerfile` a little bit and you are good to go...

#### Dockerfile

```
# FROM ubuntu:bionic
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    # python3 python3-pip \
    fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libnspr4 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils libxss1 libdbus-glib-1-2 \
    curl unzip wget vim \
    xvfb libgbm1 libu2f-udev libvulkan1

RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /usr/bin && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver && \
    rm chromedriver_linux64.zip

RUN CHROME_SETUP=google-chrome.deb && \
    wget -O $CHROME_SETUP "https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" && \
    dpkg -i $CHROME_SETUP && \
    # apt install $CHROME_SETUP && \
    apt-get install -y -f && \
    rm $CHROME_SETUP

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PATH="$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin"

# RUN pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay
# RUN pip3 install Selenium-Screenshot
WORKDIR /app

# COPY requirements.txt /app

COPY . /app

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]

# ENV APP_HOME /usr/src/app
# WORKDIR /$APP_HOME

# COPY . $APP_HOME/

# CMD tail -f /dev/null
# CMD python3 app.py
```

Now in this I am pulling `python` image and then installing all the required packages to build chrome-browser, then installing and setting up chrome-browser and `chromedriver`.

#### What you need to change

In the `Dockerfile` change `CMD` command to run your script or app name.
In the python script change the path of `chromdriver` to `/path/to/chromedriver` it will automatically detect `chromediver`.

#### Docker build fails

In case your build fails it is most probably because you may need some additional packages to install along side before install and setting google-chrome in `Dockerfile`, in the prompt it will mention you that `google-chrome depends on ~@@###` some packages you need to look up for that package online, how to install that package on ubuntu and add the installation name to `Dockerfile` `RUN` command, like this -

```
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /usr/bin && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver && \
    rm chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    {package(s) name}
```

*I have added the name at the last.*

#### Docker run command

As you are using google-chrome you need to modify your `docker run` command it should be like this -

```
docker run -p portnumber:portnumber --shm-size="2g" name_of_image
```